# Работа двух кнопок друг на друге unity3d

Tags: unity3d

Всем привет.
Есть две кнопки: большая и маленькая. Маленькая находится внутри области большой, почему-то, когда я нажимаю на маленькую, выполняется нажатие на большую. Как это исправить?

Обе кнопки UI. Выглядит следующим образом: синяя и красная область - это Button, И белый квадрат тоже.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Цветные кнопки вызывают метод onTap():

```
public class Button : MonoBehaviour {
private GameField field;
private UnityEngine.UI.Button instance;

public static int LEFT = 0;
public static int RIGHT = 1;
private int side;
public int Side
{
    get
    {
        return this.side;
    }
}
private Color color;
public Color Color
{
    get
    {
        return this.color;
    }
}

void OnEnable()
{
    field = Camera.main.GetComponent<GameField>();
    instance = this.GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Button>();
}
public void onTap()
{   
    field.getTapped(color, side);
}

public static UnityEngine.UI.Button Create(Transform parent, GameObject go, Color color, int side)
{
    GameObject temp = Instantiate(go) as GameObject;
    temp.transform.SetParent(parent, false);
    temp.GetComponent<Button>().SetColor(color);
    temp.GetComponent<Button>().side = side;
    return temp.GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Button>();
}
public void SetColor(Color col)
{
    col.a = 0.2f;
    ColorBlock currCol = instance.colors;
    currCol.normalColor = col;
    currCol.pressedColor = col;
    currCol.highlightedColor = col;
    this.instance.colors = currCol;
    this.color = col;
}
public void Cut()
{
    RectTransform temp = this.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
    temp.anchorMax = new Vector2(temp.anchorMax.x, 0.5f);
}

}
```

Белая вызывает onPauseClick():

```
public class ButtonClick : MonoBehaviour

{

public Canvas gameGUI;
public Canvas pauseGUI;
public void onPauseClick()
{
    if (State.state != State.PAUSED)
    {
        State.setPaused();
        gameGUI.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        pauseGUI.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }

    else
    {
        State.setResumed();
        gameGUI.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        pauseGUI.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }

}
public void onRestartClick()
{
    UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
}
}
```

Comment: 1) вариант - не ставить маленькую кнопку на большую. Ибо зачем кнопка на кнопке? Было бы здорово если бы объяснили сию необходимость...... 2) Raycast'oм

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, На экране имеются две кнопки, каждая размером с полэкран, и мне нужно добавить кнопку паузы

Comment: Эти две кнопки какие: UI или GUI или спрайты или еще какие?  кнопка паузы аналогичные вопросы...... зачем у вас кнопки на пол экрана? Можете это показать в вопросе визуально?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Обе кнопки UI. Выглядит следующим образом: синяя и красная область - это Button, И белый квадрат тоже.http://s017.radikal.ru/i428/1611/33/ea13b5571042.png

Comment: Это старый UI? Покажите, что ли, код?

Comment: А чем нажимаете: пальцем или мышкой? На красную фигню внизу не обращать внимание? Покажите код, как сейчас у вас всё происходит

Comment: Добавил код. На красную фигню - нет, это GameObject

Comment: @NikitaMedvedev так как происходит нажатие на красные синие и белые кнопки? Только кликом? Или пальцем? Или на белую кнопку пальцем могут надавить? Скрипт на `OnСlick` кнопки или через `EventTrigger` работает всё?........ ....Пока что если это все работает от клика мыши и от `OnClick` кнопок - то должно работать. Возможно нужно будет глубже копать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно поместить маленькую кнопку в начало списка инспектора (или родителя) следующим образом:

```
gameobject.transform.SetAsLastSibling();
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте поставить на `GraphicRaycaster` у свойства `Blocking Objects` состояние `All`. Обычно он располагается либо на `Canvas` либо на камере `Camera` в зависимости от выбранного режима `RenderMode`.

Comment: Нет. Не помогло.